# selenium server Unable to connect to the remote

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-server

I am trying to start remote driver in selenium using the following code 
at the server side

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.globalcontactcentre.org:99/wd/hub");
IWebDriver site = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capability);
```

and started selenium server using the following string :
java -jar F:\sawy\driver\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar  -port 99

and I have allowed connections through port 99 in the fire wall

but I still got this error client side

> Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it MY-IP:99
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>     at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

and even I tried to but the code in try catch statement

Comment: What happens when you try to access http://www.globalcontactcentre.org:99/wd/hub through the browser? Does it connect for you?

Comment: It gives the error
This site can’t be reached

globalcontactcentre.org refused to connect.

Comment: Selenium only accept local connection. You need a port forwarder.

Comment: how could I do this ??

Comment: what does `sudo netstat -plant | grep 4444` give you? add the output to your question